# Convergence behavior of $\sum_p \frac{1}{p \log p}$ and generalization.

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, divergent-series

The harmonic series
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \frac{1}{n}$$
is well known to be divergent. Using Cauchy condensation test one immediately sees that even
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \frac{1}{n\log n}$$
is divergent. Let $p_i$ be the $i$th prime. Euler showed in 1737 that
$$\sum_{i\in\mathbb N} \frac{1}{p_i}$$
is divergent.

**My question**: What do we know about the convergence behavior of
$$\sum_{i\in\mathbb N} \frac{1}{p_i \log p_i}?$$
**More general**: Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq \mathbb N$ be a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers with
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \frac{1}{a_n}=\infty.$$
What do we know about the convergence behavior of
$$\sum_{i\in\mathbb N} \frac{1}{a_i \log a_i}?$$

Answer (score 3):

Convergence depends just on how fast the sequence $\{a_i\}$ increases. For instance, if $a_i=p_i$, by the PNT or just its weaker version, the Chebyshev bound, we have:
$$ p_i \gg i \log i,\tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ \sum_{i\geq 2}\frac{1}{p_i \log p_i}\leq C\cdot \sum_{i\geq 2}\frac{1}{i \log^2 i}\tag{2}$$
and the RHS is convergent by the Cauchy's condensation test.

Comment: Is the limit something specific? (At least in terms of some $\zeta$-stuff.)

Comment: @quid: it would have been if the logarithm were in the numerator. In such a way, I am afraid it is just a constant with few to share with the values of the $\zeta$ function.